# How to modify source port in httpURLConnection call

Tags: android, sockets, httpurlconnection

I have a client Android app which creates a http and https connection to a server (on port 80) and I could read and write data successfully.

Problem arises when multiple instances of my client app try to connect to server from same network (same source IP address). In this case only 1 client always connects (when multiple clients try to simultaneously connect to server).

Is there any way to specify source port number in httpURLConnect call so that server opens a separate socket for each of my clients.

```java
HttpsURLConnection conns = null;
url=new URL(urlS);
conns=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();                 
conns.setDoOutput(true);
conns.setRequestMethod("POST");
conns.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(params.getBytes().length);
conns.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conns.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
conns.setConnectTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
conns.setReadTimeout(HTTP_TIMEOUT);

//send the POST out
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conns.getOutputStream());
out.print(params);
out.close();
```

Comment: Why? *What* problem? You'll always get a different local port per connection, and the server will always have a corresponding new socket.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post the solution here as it may help someone.
I removed this line from my code above and it is now working like a charm,
I could run 3 simultaneous clients on same network talking to same server.
I just removed this:

```
conns.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

Wonder what was it doing , but removing this line fixed the issue.

Comment: Err, it was telling the server to 'close' the 'connection'. Moral: don't write code when you don't know what it does.

Comment: I did that because my server is on a shared hosting and I feared that eventually server will limit the ports .

Comment: The server only needs one port. I suggest you stop guessing.